# Does TDengine database support special characters in table/column names?

Tags: database, special-characters, tdengine

I was trying to create a table in TDengine to record server load information using the following SQL:

```
taos> create table server-load-1 (ts timestamp, oneline_status bool, host-name binary(30), location-info binary(45));

DB error: syntax error near "-load-1 (ts timestamp, oneline_status bool,  (0.000201s)
taos>
```

Looks like TDengine does not support '-' in table name and column name. Is there any ways or settings to make TDengine support special characters like '*', '-', '.' in table/column names? Since my script used for importing data doesn't convert any special characters so it would be quite useful if TDengine support this and I don't need to make any changes to my script.

Comment: You could try what usually works with other DBs or SQL-dialects: enclose the name in `[]` or `""` or even `''`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It turns out backquote works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out using backquote(`) to enclose the name works for me.